# spl_autoload_register

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

This must be simple question for someone who knows about spl_autoload routines. I am using spl_auto_register functions and it works fine for anyone who is in my office network but as soon as somebody outside of the office tries to access it triggers fatal error. The error says...

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function spl_autoload_register() in /home/xxxxxxx/sitename/html/healthcare/qdpm/core/lib/symfony/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php on line 69
```

My initial thought is it has something to do with cookies. Can anyone help me in fixing this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's telling you that the function `spl_autoload_register()` is not defined. It doesn't exist. It means that SPL isn't compiled in the server, this support is not loaded, it has nothing to do with cookies.

What is the PHP version you're using? Is it more recent than 5.1.2?

Comment: It is working in all computers in my office(in wisconsin) but its not on my friends computer(in florida). This is really weird I know.

Had this been PHP version problem, it would have triggered on my computer too(which is in wisconsin)